# Possible to host different apps under /paths and map to custom domains, rather than hosting them under subdomains

Tags: subdomain, domains

Most sites like App Engine and Heroku have the URL like this:

```
https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/foo
```

Rather than this:

```
https://herokuapp.com/my-app-name/foo
```

I'm wondering (a) why this is, and (b), if there is a way to support the latter. It seems that GitHub does this with your projects in a repo with gh-pages. For example, from what I remember, given a repo like this:

```
https://github.com/myuser/myrepo
```

I can add a CNAME record to my repo, do some configuration on my DNS provider/manager elsewhere, and end up with a custom domain such as:

```
myrepodomain.com
```

My question is this. If it's possible in some way to configure a server or system such that you map the apps to a *path* rather than a subdomain, so `foo.com/myapp` rather than `myapp.foo.com`, such that you can then take that sub-path and map it to a custom domain like GitHub seemingly does in my example. If it's not possible, I'm wondering why not. I have a faint sense that cookies and session might be a problem in one case over another, or that SEO might be a problem, but maybe there are solutions.

Essentially I would like to do:

```
https://foo.com/app1/some/path
https://foo.com/app2/another/path
https://foo.com/app...
```

And then for the ones that want a custom domain, I map them to whatever they want:

```
https://foo.com/app1 -> helloworld.com
https://foo.com/app2 -> foobar.com
```

Wondering if that's at all possible, and if so, roughly how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

- Subdomains are used to prevent path crash with another user
- For the second point you will need proxy to sort traffic and send it to right place